# Почему не скрывается кнопка и текст с UI

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Скрипт предполагает скрытие кнопки и текста, после достижения 100%, но этого не происходит.
В чем может быть ошибка?
Скрипт -

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonProverka : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform target;
    [SerializeField] Transform button;
    [SerializeField] Camera cam;

    public PlayerController playerController;

    private bool hasTouchedPlayer = false;
    private bool counting = false;
    private float elapsedTime = 0f;
    private int savedPercentage = 0;

    
    private static int repairedGenerators = 0;

    public Button repairButton;
    public CanvasGroup percentageText;
    public Text generatorText;
    public float duration = 20.0f;
    public string repairedTag = "GeneratorRepaired";

    public LayerMask groundLayer;

    void Start()
    {
        SetButtonInteractable(false);
        UpdateGeneratorText();
    }

    private void SetButtonInteractable(bool isInteractable)
    {
        repairButton.interactable = isInteractable;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (counting)
        {
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

            if (elapsedTime >= duration)
            {
                counting = false;
                savedPercentage = 100;
                SetPercentageTextAlpha(0); // скрываем текст
                repairButton.interactable = false; // скрываем кнопку

                // при достижении 100% меняется тег, увеличивается счетчик и отключается кнопка
                if (gameObject.tag != repairedTag)
                {
                    gameObject.tag = repairedTag;
                    repairedGenerators++;
                    UpdateGeneratorText();

               
                    if (repairedGenerators == 3)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Все генераторы починены!");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                float percentage = Mathf.Clamp01(elapsedTime / duration);
                int displayPercentage = Mathf.RoundToInt(percentage * 100);
                UpdatePercentageText(displayPercentage);
                savedPercentage = displayPercentage;
            }
        }

        Vector3 targetOnScreen = calculateScreenPosition(target.position, cam);
        button.transform.position = targetOnScreen;
        button.gameObject.SetActive(targetOnScreen != Vector3.zero);
        percentageText.transform.position = targetOnScreen;
        percentageText.gameObject.SetActive(targetOnScreen != Vector3.zero);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, groundLayer))
            {
                counting = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private Vector3 calculateScreenPosition(Vector3 position, Camera camera)
    {
        Vector3 heading = position - camera.transform.position;
        if (Vector3.Dot(camera.transform.forward, heading) > 0)
        {
            return camera.WorldToScreenPoint(position);
        }
        return Vector3.zero;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            hasTouchedPlayer = true;
            SetButtonInteractable(true);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            hasTouchedPlayer = false;
            SetButtonInteractable(false);
            counting = false;
        }
    }

    public void StartCounting()
    {
        if (hasTouchedPlayer && gameObject.tag != repairedTag)
        {
            elapsedTime = savedPercentage / 100.0f * duration;
            counting = true;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateGeneratorText()
    {
        generatorText.text = "Repaired Generators: " + repairedGenerators;
    }

    public void StartRepairButtonClick()
    {
        playerController.StartRepair();
    }

    public void StopRepairButtonClick()
    {
        playerController.StopRepair();
    }

    private void UpdatePercentageText(int percentage)
    {
        percentageText.alpha = percentage / 100f;
    }

    private void SetPercentageTextAlpha(float alpha)
    {
        percentageText.alpha = alpha;
    }
}
```

Comment: А в остальном всё работает как задумано?

Comment: Да, притом кнопка перестает работать, но со сцены не скрывается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.interactable` отвечает не за скрытие кнопки, а за отключение, делает её ненажимаемой.

Скрыть кнопку можно так:

```
repairButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

То есть точно так же скрывается как любой другой объект со сцены.

Comment: Ответ верный, но у меня видимо в чем то ошибка, тк сначала в Start они как раз отключаются, а уже после починки пропадать должны. Буду разбираться.

Answer (score 0):

Фуууххх, час потел над кодом, тот ответ был верным, но у меня ничего не получалось, поэтому решил написать свой. В общем и целом, я добавил счезновение картинки и текста через alpha.
Код снизу -

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonProverka : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform target;
    [SerializeField] Transform button;
    [SerializeField] Camera cam;

    public PlayerController playerController;

    private bool hasTouchedPlayer = false;
    private bool counting = false;
    private float elapsedTime = 0f;
    private int savedPercentage = 0;

    private static int repairedGenerators = 0;

    public Button repairButton;
    public Text percentageText;
    public Text generatorText;
    public RawImage buttonRawImage; // ссылка на RawImage
    public float duration = 20.0f;
    public string repairedTag = "GeneratorRepaired";

    public LayerMask groundLayer;

    void Start()
    {
        SetButtonInteractable(true);
        UpdateGeneratorText();
    }

    private void SetButtonInteractable(bool isInteractable)
    {
        repairButton.interactable = isInteractable;
        UpdateRawImageAlpha(buttonRawImage, isInteractable ? 1f : 0f); // устанавливаем прозрачность RawImage
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (counting)
        {
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

            if (elapsedTime >= duration)
            {
                counting = false;
                savedPercentage = 100;
                UpdateCanvasGroupAlpha(percentageText, 0f); // скрываем текст
                UpdateRawImageAlpha(buttonRawImage, 0f); // скрываем RawImage

                if (gameObject.tag != repairedTag)
                {
                    gameObject.tag = repairedTag;
                    repairedGenerators++;
                    UpdateGeneratorText();

                    if (repairedGenerators == 3)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Все генераторы починены!");
                 
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                float percentage = Mathf.Clamp01(elapsedTime / duration);
                int displayPercentage = Mathf.RoundToInt(percentage * 100);
                percentageText.text = displayPercentage + "%";
                savedPercentage = displayPercentage;
            }
        }

        Vector3 targetOnScreen = calculateScreenPosition(target.position, cam);
        button.transform.position = targetOnScreen;
        button.gameObject.SetActive(targetOnScreen != Vector3.zero);
        percentageText.transform.position = targetOnScreen;
        percentageText.gameObject.SetActive(targetOnScreen != Vector3.zero);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, groundLayer))
            {
                counting = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private Vector3 calculateScreenPosition(Vector3 position, Camera camera)
    {
        Vector3 heading = position - camera.transform.position;
        if (Vector3.Dot(camera.transform.forward, heading) > 0)
        {
            return camera.WorldToScreenPoint(position);
        }
        return Vector3.zero;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            hasTouchedPlayer = true;
            SetButtonInteractable(true);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            hasTouchedPlayer = false;
            SetButtonInteractable(false);
            counting = false;
        }
    }

    public void StartCounting()
    {
        if (hasTouchedPlayer && gameObject.tag != repairedTag)
        {
            elapsedTime = savedPercentage / 100.0f * duration;
            counting = true;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateGeneratorText()
    {
        generatorText.text = "Repaired Generators: " + repairedGenerators;
    }

    public void StartRepairButtonClick()
    {
        playerController.StartRepair();
    }

    public void StopRepairButtonClick()
    {
        playerController.StopRepair();
    }

    private void UpdateCanvasGroupAlpha(Text text, float alpha)
    {
        Color color = text.color;
        color.a = alpha;
        text.color = color;
    }

    private void UpdateRawImageAlpha(RawImage rawImage, float alpha)
    {
        Color color = rawImage.color;
        color.a = alpha;
        rawImage.color = color;
    }
}
```